# Runtime error 3001 when using ADO Recordset.Find with more than one criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to use the `recordset.Find "name =" & me.txtbox.value`. To find a particular record/row. I can do this quite easily if i do it exactly as above searching only with 1 variable.

I tried to do the follow as i found other have done this online. `traceRecordset.Find "[PART_ID]=" & Me.txtSection.Value & " AND " & "[ID]= " & Me.txtCopy.Value`

this is the exact line of code that follows, the error does not throw on this line
`Me.txtLastscrap = traceRecordset.Fields("APROPERTY_2")`

This would give me more flexibility when populating a textbox with a particular value. It seems others have attempted this with no issues. However, i receive the following error.

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable
>   range or are in conflict with one another

Any thoughts?

NOTE: if i do `traceRecordset.Find "[PART_ID]=" & Me.txtSection.Value` it works and it also works with `traceRecordset.Find "[ID]= " & Me.txtCopy.Value` so individually they function correctly. Only when used together does it throw an error. If the types were the issue one of them would not work when used independently correct?

NOTE2: Here is my adodb connection line. Not sure if this has any effect

`Dim dbTrace As ADODB.Connection
Dim traceRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset`

`Set dbTrace = CurrentProject.Connection
        traceRecordset.Open "Select * from TRACE", _
            dbTrace, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText`

Comment: Does `me.txtboxnew = recordset.Find "column1=" & me.txtbox.value & " AND " & "column2=" & me.txtbox2.value` reproduce the error? Can you supply a [mcve]?

Comment: The datatypes of the columns and/or the text box values are important.  Perhaps you need to wrap the values in quotes or single quotes like `recordset.Find "column1='" & me.txtbox.value & "' AND " & "column2='" & me.txtbox2.value & "'"`.  Is this an ADO recordset, as opposed to an DAO recordset which is available by default in Access VBA environment?

Comment: Also, the Find method does not return a valid that you can assign to `me.txtboxnew`.  Instead, it just repositions the row to the match if found.  See [Find Method ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/find-method-ado)

Comment: I'm doubting that others have made this work using the syntax you show.  I would review the resources which claim success and see if you are really matching their syntax and/or procedure.  If you still think you are, please provide links for inspection.

Comment: i've edited the original post to contain my exact code that reproduces the error.

This is an ADODB recordset and not a DAO. Sorry for any confusion i messed up my original posts syntax. It should be corrected to exactly what i have.

Comment: It is easy to assume, but are both [ID] and [Part_ID] numeric... integers?  Just for kicks, perhaps try wrapping each expression in parenthesis like `traceRecordset.Find "([PART_ID]=" & Me.txtSection.Value & ") AND (" & "[ID]= " & Me.txtCopy.Value & ")"`.  Also, inspect the full criteria string with `Debug.Print "[PART_ID]=" & Me.txtSection.Value & " AND " & "[ID]= " & Me.txtCopy.Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ADO Recordset.Find documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/find-method-ado),

> **Only a single-column name may be specified in criteria. This method
>   does not support multi-column searches.**
>
> ...
>
> *Criteria*:
>   A String value that contains a statement specifying the column name, comparison operator, and value to use in the search.

---

Since you are already writing VBA within an Access project, DAO works just as well and as of Access 2016, the DAO Recordset type is still the default used by Forms and QueryDef objects.  DAO recordsets support FindFirst, FindNext, FindPrevious and FindLast all supporting multi-column queries.  This single feature might not justify switching from ADO, but if all you're doing is opening, searching and enumerating recordset rows, ADO doesn't provide any significant benefit.

Comment: Oh ok, was not aware of this. Thank you for your help. I don't think it will be a big change to switch from ADO to DAO. I will do that and see if it works for me!

Comment: I was also not immediately aware of this, but I did my own research... and it did not take long to discover.  Take what you get in the comments seriously and review the information... follow the links and read.  If you're having a problem with a particular object or method (i.e. function), then go to the documentation and look at the details.